# Pass a value to a react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, web, react-hooks

Got a Component that is using a separate hook created but I'm unable to pass any value to that hook which I require in my use case.

```
const onEdit = (index: number) => useMediaLinkImage(img => {

        setNodeImages(imgData => {

            imgData[index] = {
                ...imgData[index],
                image: {
                    ...imgData[index].image,
                    image: img
                }
            }


            return imgData
        })
    })
```

return --------------

```
{
            nodeImages.map(({ image, mode }, index) => <Image
                    key={index}
                    mode={mode}
                    image={image}
                    onEmpty={onEmpty}
                    onChange={onValueChange}
                    onSubmit={onSubmit}
                    onToggle={onToggle}
                    onEdit={() => onEdit(index)}
                    onAdd={addImage}
                />)
            }
```

unable to get use it as a function to get the index for the onEdit throws error

```
React Hook "useMediaLinkImage" is called in function "onEdit" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".
```

Answer (score 1):

It expects that `onEdit` is a component that should return a `JSX element` or `null` or `undefined` but you return `useMediaLinkImage` hook, because with this `arrow function` syntax `(index: number) => useMediaLinkImage` it's a shortcut for

```
(index: number) => {
  return useMediaLinkImage((img) => {
     // code ..
  })
}
```

You just need to use brackets without `return`.

```
const onEdit = (index: number) => {
   useMediaLinkImage(img => {

        setNodeImages(imgData => {

            imgData[index] = {
                ...imgData[index],
                image: {
                    ...imgData[index].image,
                    image: img
                }
            }


            return imgData
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: It did not work still the same error

Answer (score 1):

You can just call hooks inside other hooks, or inside the main body of a React component.

In you case, you have to *return* the function you want to call from the hook itself:

```js
function useMediaLinkImage(...) {
    // set your custom state here
    function update(index, ...) {
        ...
    }
    return {
        ... // return state variables from here if needed
        update
    };
}
```

Then in your component:

```js
const { update } = useMediaLinkImage(...);

const onEdit = (index: number) => {
  update(index, ...);
}
```

Comment: i wanna use the index inside the component mot inside the hook

Comment: @Snivio you can already do so - please show more code so we can help better!

Comment: was a typo at my end working now Thanks